# Conditions for the unique symmetric matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $V=CC'$ ($dim(C)=(n,k),k<n$) be a symmetric $(n,n)$ real matrix produced from unknown full-rank matrices C. I want to decompose it uniquely into the product $AA'$, $dim(A)=(n,k)$. What limitations are enough to put on A, so that the decomposition is unique within that class? I would appreciate any hints in the direction of the solution.

Comment: Is $C$ required to be a real matrix, too?

Comment: I don't think you need any assumptions: take the SVD of $V$ and you'll find two matrices $U$ and $\Sigma$ such that $V = U\Sigma U'$. Let $T$ be the first $k$ columns of $U$ and $D=\Sigma^{1/2}$ be the diagonal matrix with the square root of the first $k$ diagonal elements of $\Sigma$. Then you have that $A=UD$.

Comment: In general the decomposition $V=AA'$ cannot be unique because you can take any unitary matrix $X$ and you have that $V=AXX'A'$.

Comment: Yes, C is real. So it seems that it is unique if using the spectral decomposition and ordering eigenvalues.